# Is there a way to fix possible lossy conversion from double to long in Java?

Tags: java, optimization, double, long-integer

In the Switch optimization at the beginning of the code, where I try to create a variable representing the math.sqrt, where rx is it gives back an error that says "possibly lossy conversion from double to long". I think this is because for the sqrt it has to be a double and the rx is a long. How do I fix this?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SwitchOptimization{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner Input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter an integer: ");
        long n = Input.nextLong();
        long nHalfed = n/2;
        double rx = Double.longBitsToDouble(n);
        long squareN = Math.sqrt(rx);
        long d = 1; 
        System.out.println("Which method would you like to see?: ");
        System.out.println("1. : Un-Optimized");
        System.out.println("2. : Optimized");
        System.out.println("3. : Super Optimized!");
        System.out.println("Make your choice 1-3: ");
        System.out.print("Your Choice: ");
        int userIn = Input.nextInt();
        
switch(userIn)
        {
            case 1:
            UnoptimizedC(n,d);
            break;
            case 2:
            Optimized(n,d,nHalfed);
            break;
            case 3:
            maxOptimization(n,d,squareN);
            break;
            default:
            System.out.println("Hey dummy, enter only 1,2, or 3!");
        }
    }

    public static void UnoptimizedC(long n, long d)
    {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis( );

        do
        {
            if( n % d == 0 ) 
            {
                System.out.print(d + " ");
                d++;
            }
            else
                d++;
        }
        while( d <= n/2 );

        System.out.print(n); 
        System.out.println(" ");
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis( );
        System.out.println("Your choice of Optimized took " + ((endTime - startTime)/2000000000.0) + " seconds to run.");
    }

    public static void Optimized(long n, long d, long halfN)
    {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis( );

        do
        {
            if( n % d == 0 ) 
            {
                System.out.print(d + " ");
                d++;
            }
            d++;
        }
        while( d <= n/2);

        System.out.print(n); 
        System.out.println(" ");
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis( );
        System.out.println("Your choice of Un-Optimized took " + ((endTime - startTime)/2000000000.0) + " seconds to run.");
    }

    public static void maxOptimization(long n, long d, long squareN)
    {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis( );

        do
        {
            if( n % d == 0 ) 
            {
                System.out.print(d + " ");
                System.out.print(n/d + " ");
                d++;
            }
            else
                d++;
        }
        while(d <= squareN);

        System.out.println(" ");
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis( );
        System.out.println("Your choice of Super Optimized took " + ((endTime - startTime)/2000000000.0) + " seconds to run.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please remove all code from your question not directly related to the problem (ie nearly all of it) leaving only the very few (1 or 2) lines required to show the compilation error. Are you in fact just asking how to convert a double to a long without generating the warning (which may be ignored btw)?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the documentation for Double.longBitsToDouble() (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#longBitsToDouble-long-), it goes into how/where/why there is possible loss. I would have added this as a comment, but it's too long:

> Note that this method may not be able to return a double NaN with
> exactly same bit pattern as the long argument. IEEE 754 distinguishes
> between two kinds of NaNs, quiet NaNs and signaling NaNs. The
> differences between the two kinds of NaN are generally not visible in
> Java. Arithmetic operations on signaling NaNs turn them into quiet
> NaNs with a different, but often similar, bit pattern. However, on
> some processors merely copying a signaling NaN also performs that
> conversion. In particular, copying a signaling NaN to return it to the
> calling method may perform this conversion. So longBitsToDouble may
> not be able to return a double with a signaling NaN bit pattern.
> Consequently, for some long values,
> doubleToRawLongBits(longBitsToDouble(start)) may not equal start.
> Moreover, which particular bit patterns represent signaling NaNs is
> platform dependent; although all NaN bit patterns, quiet or signaling,
> must be in the NaN range identified above.

This is where the imprecision part is coming in, and appears to be an issue with how Java does double values versus how IEEE 754 specifies floating point numbers.